# Excel, stack columns together and filter out non-unique values?

Tags: excel

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010. I have the following spreadsheet structure

```
       A            B        C
Administrators Moderators Visitors
--------------|----------|--------
admin          mary       stephen
suadmin        bob        kevin
bob
```

I would like to create a new column such that the values of Administrators, Moderators, and Visitors are all stacked and duplicates are filtered out.

```
  D
User
-------
admin
suadmin
bob
mary
stephen
kevin
```

Currently, I copy my three columns into a new column before running the Remove Duplicates function. This is problematic because whenever I add a new name to my administrators, moderators, or visitors, I have to update this new column again.

Is it possible to have this represented as a function?

Comment: use the macro recorder to record yourself copying the three columns into one and using remove duplicates.  Then clean up the code and use it.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @jeffreyweir look at the first sentence.

Comment: Whoops. Missed that.

Comment: Have posted an answer suggesting a solution involving PowerQuery at that other thread.